# Can an android device connect to a sony camera without wifi?

Tags: android, camera, sony

I'm thinking about using the Sony Camera Remote API, but before I start I'd like to know if it's possible to create a connection between an Android device and a Sony camera **without wifi**. I'd like to know because I'm developing an app where taking pictures is one of the functionalities and that needs to happen even when there is no wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Camera Remote API only works over WiFi, so there is no other way to control the camera.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work that way, but thanks for the response

Comment: I just have two questions I'd like to ask to be sure:
1. If I were to be for example outside (with no Wi-Fi network to connect to) could I still establish a connection between the two devices?
2. Is it it possible to connect your phone to 3G/4G and then have the phone act like an Access point and connect the camera to that to establish the connection?

Comment: 1.  Yes, the connection works over direct WiFi so you only need an Android device and the camera.  2.  This is not supported, only direct WiFi is supported for the API.